# The following classes could not be instantiated: - androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-xml, androidx

I'm currently working on an app in android studio that requires using the recyclerview. After writing the code, the app seems to show no error so far except my XML design tab that issues out the following output on the issues section - "The following classes could not be instantiated:
`androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

I've tried looking for a solution to it on this site but couldn't find any similar issue.

This is the code I used for recyclerview: <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

I as well implemented it on build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation '"androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"'
```

I also added android.view.LayoutInflater to the main java file

Anything else I didn't do correctly?

My layout.xml file, the issue message for it, and the build.gradle are below:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRxK9.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9qR4.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR4vR.png

Comment: Add _com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1_ dependency.

Comment: it still hasn't fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm not sure whether it is possible to have a recyclerview as root of a fragment.

Comment: Yes, it's there by default

Comment: Well, in theory that's all that's required to get it working. No more implementations required. Can you show your complete layout and also how you set it up?

Comment: Sure, I've posted the screenshots up, please check it out

Comment: @Chinez How do you use `fragment_task_list.xml`? Where do you include or inflate it?

Comment: I'm still getting the same result but thanks and yeah I added android.view.LayoutInflater to the main java file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224264/discussion-between-chinez-and-tobi).

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by deleting a wrong code on one of my layout.xml files but thanks for your support tho